# `TextField.Input` loses focus everytime `useState` rerenders on type

Tags: reactjs, next.js, themes

`TextField.Input` from `@radix-ui/themes` is losing focus everytime useState set is triggered `onChange`. This behavior doesn't happend in vanilla inputs using React. Is there any config I am missing or is this a bug?

The same exact config works in vanilla Input type=Text. Had the same issue in another component but managed to fix it using useContext instead of useState because I used a global state.

```
const [projectBody, setProjectBody] = useState<ProjectForm>({
    name: "",
    description: "",
    category: "",
    budget: "",
  });

const handleInputChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    setProjectBody({ ...projectBody, [name]: value });
 };

<form action="" method="POST" className="flex flex-col gap-4">
      <label htmlFor="name">Name *</label>
        <TextField.Input
          size="3"
          name="name"
          id="name"
          placeholder="Cool App..."
          defaultValue={projectBody.name}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
</form>
```

Project deps:

- Next: 13.4.19
- @radix-ui/themes: 1.1.2
- million: 2.6.0-beta.11